# Deploying spring boot application on AWS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, properties, tags

I have problem with deploying my application.

I want to save tags like jwtSecret etc. in AWS. When I remove these old (in java properties), I cant create .jar because of errors.

How can I do this without typing secret tags in properties ?

Comment: Where are you deploying your Spring app. Are you using Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: yes its Beanstalk

Comment: How are you creating your Spring JAR? Are you using a Maven project?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm using maven

Comment: There are quite a few Spring boot examples that use AWS Java V2 API and the Spring framework, For example, there are Redshift, DynamoDB, and many other examples. The only thing is none of them use  tags like jwtSecret. So I am not sure that they will help you.

Comment: Are you creating your JAR using mvn package

Comment: mvn clean install